# Transition in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add an Accordion in a project with smooth transition effect through javascript only.

In the code below,the transition is 200s, but it does not show a transition effect. I have tried a lot of codes but it did not worked. I want to do it through pure javascript.

Also, after opening and closing of the accordion the hover effect is gone. Is there any way to fix it with javascript.

```js
function openaccn() {
var i = document.getElementById('acc');
var j = document.getElementById('acc_contnt');
if (j.style.display === "block") {
      i.style.textDecoration = "none";
      i.style.color = "#fff";
      j.style.transition = "all 2000s";
      j.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      i.style.textDecoration = "underline";
      i.style.color = "deepskyblue";
      j.style.transition = "all 2000s";
      j.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
nav {
background: grey;
width: 100%;
}
ul li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 2px 5px;
}
ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: block;
padding:5px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li a:hover {
 color: deepskyblue;
}
.accrdncontnt {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background:skyblue;
padding: 10px 5%;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu</li>
<li><a id="acc" href="#" onclick= openaccn();>Accordion(click to open)</li>
<li><a href="#">terms</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="acc_contnt" class="accrdncontnt"><p>This dropdown should display in smooth transition</p><div>
```

Comment: The display property is not transitionable, so you are switching from none to block and back from block to none instantly.

Comment: You have to transition a property that can be calculated. The only change you are making to `j`, is the display. And you cannot transition between `block` and `none`, since there are no intermediate steps. Try transitioning the height, or min-height, or some other property you can express in units or percentages.

Comment: Ok, and what about the hover effect that is gone from the <a> tag after if someone opens and close the accordion. @shilly

Comment: @gyanendra Not entirely sure, but probably has something to do with that inline CSS takes priority over the external stylesheet. Hence I never change the style property with JS, I only toggle CSS classes so that the CSS stylesheet keeps it's original cascade. I'll try writing an answer.

Comment: @shilly Thanks, So that its because of specificity. but a solution to overcome that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the styling the most and added the closing tags in the HTML.
I removed all the inline CSS as I stated in my comment to avoid specificity problems.

The result is not perfect, since the text inside the `<p>` looks kinda weird, but else we'd have to transition the min-height, or the scaleY or something else that allows us to hide the contents of `#accrdncontnt` without using display none. visibility hidden would be perfect if there's no other content below the accordion.

```js
function openaccn() {
  var i = document.getElementById('acc');
  var j = document.getElementById('acc_contnt');
  i.classList.toggle( 'active' );
  j.classList.toggle( 'active' );
}
```

```css
nav {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding:5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li a:hover {
 color: deepskyblue;
}
/* overwrite the "ul li a text-decoration: none;" rule above us */
#acc.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.accrdncontnt {
  /* we cannot set the display to none, if we want to transition height */
  /* display none means the element is not considered is the layout */
  /* so we cannot calculate a transition on a non existing element */
  /* we could use visbility hidden instead of display none to hide the element */
  /* but that would make the empty space always visible */
  /* we want to transition the height */
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
   /* add transition here, 2000ms or 2s */
   /* 2000s will take more than an hour, so it's probably a typo */
  transition: height 2s;
}
/* to make the content of .accrdncontnt invisible until the parent is active */
.accrdncontnt > * {
  display: none;
}
.accrdncontnt.active {
  height: 100px;
  /* add the padding here, else we'd always seee the blue background of the padding */
  padding: 10px 5%;
  transition: height 2s;
}
.accrdncontnt.active > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="acc" href="#" onclick= openaccn();>Accordion(click to open)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">terms</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="acc_contnt" class="accrdncontnt">
  <p>This dropdown should display in smooth transition</p>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, Got it

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code structer mostly wrong(Not closed link tags etc.), i recreate your project. `display` property not support `transition` property, so you can use visibliy and opacity together for transition effect.

```js
var i = document.getElementById('acc');
var j = document.getElementById('acc_contnt');
i.addEventListener('click', function() {
  j.classList.toggle('toggled');
})
```

```css
nav {
background: grey;
width: 100%;
}
ul li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 2px 5px;
}
ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: block;
padding:5px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li a:hover {
 color: deepskyblue;
}

.accrdncontnt {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background:skyblue;
  padding: 10px 5%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: 250ms ease
}

.accrdncontnt.toggled{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a id="acc" href="#">Accordion(click to open)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">terms</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="acc_contnt" class="accrdncontnt"><p>This dropdown should display in smooth transition</p><div>
```